# How to 'move' the values of a 2D NumPy array according to a deplacement matrix

Tags: python, numpy

`DD` is a 2D-array of size `(Nx, Ny)`.
`Ux` and `Uy` are two 2D-arrays of integers of the same size, which define how to move the values of `DD` in a new matrix `DD_new`.

For example, if `Ux[0,0]=2` and `Uy[0,0]=3`, then the value `DD[0,0]` will be stored in `DD_new[2,3]`. If several values of `DD` need to be stored in the same emplacement of `DD_new`, they will be summed.

I am looking for an optimized script to do this "deplacement" as fast as possible.

I already have a short script, but if someone knows how to improve it by using matrix and array manipulation, it will help me:

```
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(range(Nx), range(Ny))

XX_new = (XX + Ux).astype(int)
YY_new = (YY + Uy).astype(int)

for ix in range(Nx):
    for iy in range(Ny):
        x_new = XX_new[ix, iy]
        y_new = YY_new[ix, iy]
        if (x_new >= 0) and (x_new < Nx) and (y_new >= 0) and (y_new < Ny):
            DD_new[x_new, y_new] += DD[XX[ix, iy], YY[ix, iy]]
```

Also, if someone knows how to generalize this problem with non-integer matrices `Ux` and `Uy`, and by depatching the values of `DD` on several neighbor emplacement of the matrix `DD_new`, it can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
import numpy as np

DD = [[ 1,  2,  3, 4],
      [ 5,  6,  7, 8],
      [ 9, 10, 11, 12]]
Ux = [[ 0,  1,  2,  0],
      [ 1,  2,  0,  1],
      [ 2,  0,  2,  1]]
Vx = [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
      [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
      [ 0,  1,  2,  3]]
DDnew = np.zeros_like(DD)
np.add.at(DDnew, (Ux, Vx), DD)
print(DDnew)
# [[ 1 10  7  4]
#  [ 5  2  0 20]
#  [ 9  6 14  0]]
```